# .NET/C# Library for WebDAV with NTLM/Kerberos

Tags: c#, .net, kerberos, webdav, ntlm

I want to connect to WebDAV-Servers that use Kerberos and NTLM. The WebDAV-Libraries I found so far for .NET/C# are supporting Basic Authentication only.

Do you know such a library? (in best case OpenSource, or at least free ;) )

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What kind of server are you wanting to connect to?

Comment: I know the one Server is a Sharepoint-Server using NTLM, the other one I don't know what it is exactly build up with. They both do support WebDAV, and it is working with Windows 7/8, but not with OS X, which further indicates that NTLM /Kerberos is used for this Sharepoint.

Comment: OK, in that case I don't have any suggestions. If you'd told me it was an Exchange Server I would have suggested switching from WebDAV to EWS, Exchange Web Services.